# Is there a way to make atom move faster without heating them?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, reference-frames, atomic-physics, speed

The more heat you add the faster the atom will move. This is something that is common knowledge. My question is it possible to make the atoms in let's say a gas move faster without adding heat of a large volume of heat?

Comment: Do you want the centre of mass fixed? What exactly counts as 'adding heat'? If I use magnetic fields to heat it up, does that count?

Comment: Faster relative to what?

Comment: Use an ion accelerator...

Answer (score 4):

If you take a bottle of gas and carry it with you on a supersonic plane, then the molecules will go much faster without the temperature changing.

If you let pressurized gas flow through a well-designed nozzle ([De Laval nozzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle)), the gas will accelerate to supersonic velocity (i.e., faster than the original thermal speed of the molecules) while the temperature of the gas decreases.

Note that the temperature of high-speed gases is a tricky subject; a thermomemeter moving along with the gas stream will sense a lower temperature than a stationary thermometer. The former measures the *static temperature*, while the latter measures the *recovery temperature* (depends on the shape of the thermometer probe). There is also the *stagnation temperature*, which represents the energy of the molecules regardless of whether it is due to thermal (random) motion or due to the kinetic energy of a gas jet.

So, with the gas bottle on a plane, the static temperature doesn't change, but the stagnation temperature increases for an observer who stays on the ground. Gas flowing through a nozzle (assuming that the nozzle is thermally insulated) does not change in stagnation temperature, but its static temperature drops.

Comment: So what your saying us by changing the speed of the environment that surround the gas or how the gas comes out it will change the molecules speed without heating it? Makes sense.

Comment: Sort of. Note that "heating" strictly means "adding heat to a system"; with supersonic gas flows, the static temperature may still decrease even though the gas is heated.

Comment: Velocity is relative, so you could also move away from the gas at high speed and argue that the velocity of the gas (relative to you) has increased.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer, if I did not misunderstood your question, is to adiabatically compress the gas, both pressure and temperature will raise.

Comment: To further demonstrate this, first law gives $\delta U = dQ -PdV$. Compress the gas adiabatically (as you said adding no heat) will increase internal energy, which will increase temperature. Increasing temperature will increase molecular speed, which is part of reason why pressure value increases.